# compare a long list with strings in dataframe and on the basis of matching populate the dataframe in Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, comparison, string-matching

I've aminor dataset I've to extract only computer science terms out of it so there is list1 to which i've to compare my dataset for this task.

https://www.aminer.org/oag2019

list1 = ['document types', 'surveys and overviews', 'reference works', 'general conference proceedings', 'biographies', 'general literature', 'computing standards, rfcs and guidelines', 'cross-computing tools and techniques',......]

total count of list1 is 2112 computer science terms from ACM.

data frame to which I've to compare(string comparison) list1  in a data frame column in the form of

df_train14year['keywords'].head()

0    "nmr spectroscopy","mass spectrometry","nanost...
1    "plk1","cationic dialkyl histidine","crystal s...
2    "case-control","child","fuel","hydrocarbons","...
3    "Ca2+ handling","CaMKII","cardiomyocyte","cont...
4
Name: keywords, dtype: object

in each of these lists in dataframe there are max 10 keywords min (3) in each and there are millions of records in dataframe.

so I've to compare each keywords with original list1 if more then 3 words are matching in both lists and populate a dataframe with those values, substrings match may also be needed.

how to do this task inefficient way in python, what I've done is by for loop to each keyword compared to the whole list and there are three loops in it, so it is inefficient.

````
# for i in range(5):
#    df.loc[i] = ['<some value for first>','<some value for second>','<some value for third>']

count  = 0;
i = 0;
for index, row in df_train14year.iterrows():
  # print("index",index)
  i=1+1;
  # if(i==50):
  #   break
  for outr in row['keywords'].split(","):
      #print(count)   
      if (count>1):
          # print("found1")
          count = 0;
          break;
      for inr in computerList:
          # outr= outr.replace("[","")   # i skip the below three lines because i applied the pre- processing on data to remove the [] and "
          # outr= outr.replace("]","")
          outr= outr.replace('"',"")
          #print("outr",outr,"inr",inr)
          if outr in inr:
              count = count+1
              if (count>10):
                #print("outr",outr,"inr",inr)
                # print("found2")
                # df12.loc[i] = [index,row['keywords']]
                #df12.insert(index,"keywords",row['keywords'])
                df14_4_match = df14_4_match.append({'abstract': row['abstract'],'keywords': row['keywords'],'title': row['title'],'year': row['year']}, ignore_index=True)
                break;
          # else:
          #     print('not found')```
````

Answer (score 0):

kewwords = ["nmr spectroscopy","mass spectrometry","nanos"] rows in the data frame

prprocessing: 
`dfk['list_keywords']=[[x for x in j.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split('"')[1:-1] if x not in[',',' , ',', ']] for j in dfk['keywords']]`

after converting the orgional list to set

`dfk['set_keywords']=dfk['list_keywords'].map(lambda x: set(x))`

we compare the intersection of kewordlist and computerlist(list1) mentioned in question
to get number of items or keywords matched

`dfk['set_keywords']=dfk['set_keywords'].map(lambda x:x.intersection(proceseedComputerList))`

get the length with this function

`dfk['len_keywords']=dfk['set_keywords'].map(lambda x:len(x))`

sort in ascending order

````
dfk.head()```
````